# Laravel convert strings to clickabe links

Tags: php, laravel, preg-replace

I am trying to convert `links`, `mail addresses` and `numbers` to links from my description column but I only can make 1 of them to work at the time, **what I'm looking for is solution to `preg_replace` multiple conditions.**

Here is what I have currently that converts links to clickable `a` tags:

```
public function getDescriptionAttribute($string) {
  return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">$1</a>', $string);
}
```

`Logic`

1. If description has link convert to clickable (http/https)
2. If description has mail address convert to clickable (mailto)
3. If description has numbers convert to clickable (tel)

let say I have following string in my database (description column)

```
http://google.com

tester@gmail.com

+1818254545400
```

what I get from that string is following result (based on my code above)

`Screenshot`

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might for example use an approach using a pattern with 3 capture groups, one for each option.

Then use preg_match_callback to check for the group values, and based on that determine the replacement.

```
(https?://\S+)|([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)|(\+\d+)
```

You can make the pattern for the groups as specific as you would like of course.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6i1RCd/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/7e52T)

```
function getDescriptionAttribute($string) {
    $pattern = "~(https?://\S+)|([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)|(\+\d+)~";
    
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
        
        $template = '<a href="%1$s%2$s" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">%2$s</a>';
        
        if ($matches[1] !== "") return sprintf($template, "", $matches[1]);        
        if ($matches[2] !== "") return sprintf($template, "mailto:", $matches[2]);        
        if ($matches[3] !== "") return sprintf($template, "tel:", $matches[3]);
    }, $string);    
}

$str = 'http://google.com
tester@gmail.com
+1818254545400';

echo getDescriptionAttribute($str);
```

Output

```
<a href="http://google.com" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">http://google.com</a>
<a href="mailto:tester@gmail.com" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">tester@gmail.com</a>
<a href="tel:+1818254545400" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">+1818254545400</a>
```

Comment: what is the regex code for hashtags(#xxxxx) and mentions (@xxxxx)?

Comment: @mafortis You can find an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163365/regex-for-mentions or for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384136/finding-mentions-in-string